# What is Apache Giraph's consistency model? Is it ACID compliant?

Tags: apache, hadoop, consistency, giraph

The title pretty much sums it up. I am trying to figure out what kind of consistency Giraph provides. Is it ACID compliant? Does it leave that up to the Hadoop framework?

Comment: Where exactly would you need ACID in a batch processing framework for graphs?

Comment: It's not a database. Why it should have ACID property?